# The declared package <package name> does not match the expected package "" in VS code

Tags: java, class, visual-studio-code, import, package

This is the error I get in VS code when I try to make a package in a simple program

```
The declared package "mypack" does not match the expected package "" Java(536871240)
```

[image: Aclass.java]
[image: Bclass.java]

Aclass java file gets compiled. But after compiling Bclass java file it gives this compile-time error

[image: Aclass compile]
[image: Bclass compile error]

This is Aclass java file code

```
package mypack;

class A {
    void MethodA() {
        System.out.println("This is class A");
    }
}

class Aclass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A();
        a.MethodA();
    }
}
```

This is Bclass java file code

```
import mypack.*;

class B {
    void MethodB() {
        System.out.println("This is class B");
    }
}

class Bclass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B b = new B();
        b.MethodB();
        A a = new A();
        a.MethodA();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic of packages, e.g. [this one from `oracle.com`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The declared package "mypack" does not match the expected package ""
> Java(536871240)

It's because you didn't put `.java` files in the folder `mypack`.

The second error is there're `B`, `A` in `Bclass.java`, but the compiling command didn't include them, so you should compile multiple java files by the command

```
javac -d ./ mypack\*.java
```

Then execute it by `javac mypack.Bclass`, you can get right result:

[image]

Comment: Actually I want to keep my java files in a folder name PROGRAMS and then I want to keep all the class files in mypack folder . I search through google and after I found out to clean java workspace (ctrl + shift + P then java clean) after that I am able to create package and able to import packages BUT THIS ERRORS ARE STILL THERE

Comment: 1)  package pack.A;   The declared package "pack.A" does not match the expected package ""    @Molly Wang-MSFT

Comment: 2) import pack.B;      The import pack cannot be resolved   @Molly Wang-MSFT

Comment: Basically i want to put Aclass and Bclass .class files in a package "mypack" and want to import Bclass from mypack in Cclass file .So I am able to do this by 1) javac -d . *.java     
 2) javac Cclass.java  BY DOING THIS COMMANDS OUTPUT COMES BUT THAT ERRORS IN CODE ARE STILL SHOWN WITH RED LINES . HOW TO REMOVE THAT ERRORS ?

Comment: There's a setting called "java.project.outputPath" to customize where stores .class files, but it only worked in no build tools project which is generated by Java: Create Java Project--> no build tools from Command Palette. so, the setting can't be applied in your current project structure. Maybe you can create no build tools project then try again.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to right click on below Files in the **Explorer Tab in Visual Studio code** and then just Select **Remove Folder** from java source path.

It was helpful for me and now there are no issues.

Again remember, **right click > remove folder from java source path**